# Can umask be used for special permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, chmod, umask

Is there a way to set special permissions on files and directories during its creation using umask or some other command ?

i.e if I set umask to 0000 , the file permissions will become 0666 and for directories it will be 0777 . In any case , default special permissions are not set .

Answer (score 1):

#### No, it is not possible to set special permissions with umask.

Quoting the [Arch Wiki: umask](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Umask#Meaning_of_the_mode_mask):

> The suid, sgid and sticky bits of the mask are ignored.

Use `chmod` to set gid and uid bits.